# How to get streaming bitrate with MediaPlayer?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm developing a stream video app in Android with `MediaPlayer`. The problem is that I need to show the current bitrate, but I haven't found any valid suggestions on how to do get it?

Here is how I'm setting the video url to play:

```
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(VIDEO_PATH);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.init();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I don't know if the only way to get that working is using `ExoPlayer` (which I've read it may be possible)

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you cannot do this with `MediaPlayer` but you can use `MediaMetadataRetriever`, which is available since API level 10, i.e., quite a while ago.

```
  int getBitRate(String url) {
        final MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        try {
            mmr.setDataSource(url, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
            return Integer.parseInt(mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_BITRATE));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return 0;
        } finally {
            mmr.release();
        }
    }
```

The disadvantage this can have is that you will make an extra HTTP request for getting the metadata (only an RTT if you are *streaming from an URI*; if you are reading from an *file descriptor* it could be more serious).  Hopefully no big deal.